# Can I run a webserver with ts-node or similar with a codebase of mixed JS and TS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ts-node

I have a server running Node that is written in JavaScript.  I would like to begin adding new features in TypeScript, and gradually convert the old code as we go.

I also don't want to recompile manually every time I make changes, using ts-node would be ideal if I had a purely ts codebase.

Is there configuration for ts-node that will ignore js files in the mix, or another launcher wrapper that can handle this logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this option to your tsconfig.json would do the trick:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "checkJs": false
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... that's what I thought.  Something else must be wonky.